# Customise the color of buttons in the RPPreviewViewController (ReplayKit)

Tags: swift, button, colors, replaykit

I have recorded a video sequence with RPScreenRecorder. Everything works perfectly fine.

**Now I want to customize the UI of the preview controller.
How can I change the color of the cancel and save buttons?
Yeah, in general I know how to change the color of a UIBarButtonItem:**

```
let cancelBtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissView))
cancelBtn.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red], for: .normal)
```

**But I can not find the references of the buttons in the preview (RPPreviewViewController).**

```
func stopRecorder() {
        recorder.stopRecording { [unowned self] (preview, error) in            
            guard let previewVC = preview else {
                return
            }
            previewVC.previewControllerDelegate = self
            previewVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(previewVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code while presenting/pushing view controller

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = Colors.redColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white, NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFontWeightBold)]
```

Please note: Do not forget to reset all this value while dismissing/pop view controller as all this value applies to all navigation controller through out the application.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I have tried this. I also tried this previewVC.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = .systemRed. The navigationController is nil.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RPPreviewViewController in SwiftUI, I was able to change the color of the buttons in the nav bar of the preview controller using accentColor.

```
if isShowPreviewVideo {
    replayKitPreview
      .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
      .accentColor(Color(hex: 0x0096FF))
      .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```